# Why do I not have any of the steam achievements for Borderlands?

Tags: steam, achievements, borderlands

I have multiple characters 30+, one of my characters has most of the in game achievements, I have played online and have a gamespy account. I have a legal copy (obviously), yet in steam profile for the game I have 0 achievements. How come?

Comment: as per 5th august I now have the steam achievements.

Comment: though not all of them, some you have to redo (like discovering zones) and some you have to refresh (killing one mob with my talent gave me 15 kills with talent one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common to all Borderlands players on Steam right now, as achievements are disabled/not working yet. http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1390120

Comment: I just felt my answer got answered, but I'll move the accepted to you if that makes you feel all fuzzy inside :)

Comment: ack, sorry, I didn't mean to come off like that at all.

Answer (score 2):

Borderlands previously did not include steam achievements. If it just came out recently, I'd give them a day or so to get database issues sorted out.

In general, you can determine whether or not a game has steam achievements by checking the community box in the right edge of the game's profile in the steam store.

Compare: http://store.steampowered.com/app/440/ (364 achievements listed)

to: http://store.steampowered.com/app/8980/ (no achievements listed)

Comment: Achievements just came out today; that page has not yet been updated. http://img822.imageshack.us/i/borderlands2.png/

Comment: Aha. I was not aware. Answer will be kept for posterity.

Comment: :/

I gave you a +1, even.

Answer (score 1):

A number of achievements (like Destroyed the Destroyer and Discovered various areas) won't be unlocked retroactively.  You have to satisfy the conditions of those achievements in game.  Achievements that are tied to completing missions or challenges will be unlocked retroactively when the character used to complete said mission or challenge is first played after receiving the achievements update.  For instance, the character level achievements, 12 Days Of Pandora, or Get A Little Blood On The Tires were awarded to me retroactively.

Answer (score 0):

If it means anything, I reinstalled last night and got on a level 37 hunter at about 9:00 EST  and had a bunch of achievements retroactively given to me.

Answer (score 0):

well, my borderlands is a CD version, and im not sure it works on steam achievements, as it's registered as a "non-steam game". fully legit, blah de blah, got all the DLCS, done some online etc. but no achievements. a bit of a shame really, i think steam should allow you to fully register your CD copy...